# Android Volley returning strange html

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I am trying to use volley to send a parameter via POST to a php script and it is just supposed to return an echo. However, instead of the simple echo, it returns this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://wvw.vodafone.com.au/stelprd/fragments/vca_new_grid/js/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
    background:url("https://wvw.vodafone.com.au/stelprd/fragments/vfa2_frag_megamenu/img/body_bg_high.gif") repeat-x scroll left top #FFFFFF !important;
    }
    #orientation {
    left:-1000px;
    position:absolute;
    top:-1000px;
    }
    #page-cont {
    width:960px;
    margin:0px auto;
    }
    #vha-header {
    margin:0 3px 10px 3px;
    z-index:1000;
    position:relative;
    }
    ul#menu li.top-level {
    position:static;
    z-index:1500;
    }
    ul#menu li .nav-item-dd {
    left:0;
    }
    ul#menu li .nav-item-dd {
    z-index:2000;
    }
    .grid {
    display:block;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-top:0;
    width:960px !important;
    }
    /* global nav */
    #global-nav-wrap {
    padding-bottom:20px;
    height:40px;
    }
    #top-globalnav {
    float:left;
    height:40px;
    position:relative;
    padding-left:80px;
    }
    #top-globalnav li {
    float:left;
    margin-top:10px;
    }
    #top-globalnav li a {
    display:block;
    font-size:1.178em;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#f4f4f4;
    border-left:0px;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    border:solid 1px #d3d3d3;
    border-left:0px;
    border-right:0px;
    background-image:url(https://wvw.vodafone.com.au/stelprd/fragments/vfa2_frag_megamenu/img/vha_mm_pipe.gif);
    background-position:0px 0px;
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    }
    #top-globalnav li a span {
    padding:0px 20px;
    line-height:28px;
    display:block;
    }
    #top-globalnav li.global-item-last a {
    border-right:solid 1px #d3d3d3;
    }
    #top-globalnav li.nav-item-on,#top-globalnav li.global-item-active {
    margin-top:5px;
    }
    #top-globalnav li.nav-item-on a,#top-globalnav li.global-item-active a {
    background-color:#fff;
    background-image:url(https://wvw.vodafone.com.au/stelprd/fragments/vfa2_frag_megamenu/img/vha_mm_pipe.gif);
    background-position:0px 0px;
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    border-top:0px;
    border-bottom:0px;
    border-bottom:none;
    }
    #top-globalnav li.nav-item-on a span,#top-globalnav li.global-item-active a span {
    border:0px;
    }
    #top-globalnav li.nav-item-on a span,#top-globalnav li.global-item-active a span {
    text-indent:0px;
    display:block;
    line-height:33px;
    margin-right:-1px;
    background-image:url(https://wvw.vodafone.com.au/stelprd/fragments/vfa2_frag_megamenu/img/vha_mm_pipe.gif);
    background-position:100% 0px;
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    border-top:solid 1px #d3d3d3;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#fff;
    border-left:solid 1px #d3d3d3;
    text-indent:-1px;
    padding:0px 21px 0px 20px;
    border-bottom:none;
    padding-bottom:1px;
    cursor:pointer;
    }
    #top-globalnav li a:link,#top-globalnav li a:visited,#top-globalnav li a:hover,#top-globalnav li a:active {
    }
    #top-globalnav li a span {
    }
    #top-globalnav li
```

I have tested my code on other activities and it works properly. This is very strange.

This is my sending code

```
private void checkInternet(){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.CHECK_INTERNET,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.d("VOLLEYRESLOC",response);
                        if(response.equals("Connection Established")){
                            Log.d("VOLLEYRESPONSE","RESPONDED");
                        }else{
                            Log.d("VOLLEYRESPONSE","NOTRESPONDED");
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d("VOLLEYRESERR",error.toString());
                    }

                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String>params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put(Constants.params_check,"Connection");
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

And the PHP Script

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
        $status = $_POST["status"];
        echo $status." Established";
    }       
?>
```

Can anyone help me with this? I'm not sure what is going on especially when the php code is so simple.

Comment: Could it be my webhost? I'm testing this using the 000webhost